# Storing state in service layer

Tags: .net, design-patterns, c#-3.0

I have a base service class, and I have a bunch of services, is it good/bad practice to store data on a service class?

For example:

```
public interface IFunkyService
{
  void AddComment(int quoteid, string comment);
  void SetProirirty(int quoteid, Importance proirity);
}

public class FunkyService : CustomServiceBase, IFunkyService
{

 private readonly IRepo _repo;
 private readonly IUserSession _user;
 public FunkyService(IRepo repo, IUserSession user)
 {
  _repo = repo;
  _user = user;
 }


     public void SetProirirty(int quoteid, Important priority)
     {

      //get quote object then persists

     } 

    public void AddComment(int quoteid, string comment)
     {

      //get quote object then persists

     }

}
```

Can I simply just have a private method that stores the quote object on the class?
e.g.

```
private Quote _quote {get;set;} //store on the class???

private void GetQuote(int quoteid)
{
 _quote = _repo.single(quoteid); //or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the value in the class is only going to live as long as the service object itself.  A service object is created and destroyed with every request to the service, so `Quote` will only live during the length of a single request.  The only purpose I can see for something like that is a per-request cache (i.e., during a single request you reference the `Quote` object five times.  You should only need to actually look it up from the backing store once).

1. Client makes request to server
2. Server instantiates `FunkyService` class
3. Client calls `GetQuote`
4. Server populates `Quote` in the class.
5. Client completes call.
6. Server finalizes request, disposes `FunkyService` object from (2).
7. The value of `Quote` is no longer stored in the class because the object is gone.

**Edit:** It appears the reason you want to do this is so that retrieving a quote object is done in one place, but it doesn't get called over and over again (i.e., making multiple requests to the database when only one is needed).  You can implement the cacheable property design pattern to have a per-request cache without using a class variable.  It would look something like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, Quote> _quoteCache = 
    new Dictionary<int, Quote>(); // cache storage - NEVER ACCESS DIRECTLY

public Quote GetQuote(int quoteid)
{
    // cache is invalid, so populate
    if (!_quoteCache.ContainsKey(quoteid))
    {
        _quoteCache.Add(quoteid, _repo.single(quoteid));
    }

    // return back to caller
    return _quoteCache[quoteid];
}
```

In the example above, the cache stores each unique quoteid retrieved from the database.  So if you call `GetQuote(5)` five times in a row, it is only retrieved from the database via `_repo` a single time.  However if you call `GetQuote(6)` then it goes to the database again because that quote is not available from the cache.  After that, both 5 and 6 are still stored in the cache until the service request is finished and disposed.

**Edit2:** In the example you provided:

```
var t = GetTags(_quote);
// then do something with t, I may pass to another method:
if(IsClosed(_quote)){}
```

Instead of referencing a class variable, have your repository return a `Quote` object and pass that reference along, like this:

```
private Quote GetQuote(int quoteid)
{
    return _repo.single(quoteid); //or whatever
}

// other code
var q = GetQuote(quoteid); // get the quote once
var t = GetTags(q);  // q doesn't have to retrieve from repo again
if (IsClosed(q)) {}
// etc.
```

Comment: The biggest benefit for me to do this is to keep the "Get me a quote object in one place", if I call one method or pass the object to another method I dont want to reinstantiate the object each time. In one call I want to complete my task, if the tradeoff is that I cant make another call with this object (after the completion of 7. above) that is fine. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you quite.  You should be able to pass the `Quote` object along from method to method without getting from the database over and over again by passing it as a parameter.  If you are storing it in the class to keep it as a reference between methods that is actually a **bad idea** (like global variables).  Can you add some more code demonstrating an example of the chain of methods that would be called?

Comment: You can definitely have "Get me a quote object in one place," there's nothing wrong with that.  But instead of storing it in a global class variable, return it from the method `private Quote GetQuote(int quoteid) { return _repo.single(quoteid); }`.  Then pass along the reference from method to method.  Make sense?

Comment: bad idea... ok, I will add some code, yes I will be passing the object from method to method but I want to store the quote object on the service class itself just for this request.

Comment: Why do you need to store it on the class?  You can implement the cacheable design pattern.  I'll add an example to my answer. **Edit:** I have updated with an example.  I am storing it in the class like you are, but it should never be accessed directly.  It is only used as a cache, so all callers still use `GetQuote` to get the quote object, never `_quote` itself.  Make sense?

Comment: Why store on class? Well in any method at any given time, providing quote has been instantiated, I can say: var t = GetTags(_quote); then do something with t, I may pass to another method: if(IsClosed(_quote)){} or whatever...

Comment: @Haroon: Right. Use the method I provide above which doesn't pass the class variable along.  Everyone should get the Quote from only one place (by calling `GetQuote`).  GetQuote manages the cache internally to make sure multiple requests for the same object are efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies in your case but when switching a stateless service (or generally any component) to being statefull you need to consider a few issues:

1. Thread Safety - your must make the state immutable of ensure thread safe access to that state. Also keep in mind that most tracking ( state tracking ) ORMs don't do so well when same instances are accessed from multiple threads.
2. Consider the possibility that the service is deployed in multiple instances (say for load balancing) in the future. If the state is not immutable you can end up with out of sync instances for the same entity.
3. If the reason for doing this is Caching and performance improvements you can design an orthogonal caching strategy that can avoid the above problems - ex using an NHibernate cache provider or caching data in the application layer.

As a rule of thumb try to keep as much as possible of your code stateless. It's safer to work with, allows you to improve performance by doing async operations and I also think it's easier for others to understand it. When you need to keep state, especially shared state make sure all access to it is thread safe and that is very well documented.

Comment: So even if I have to access the database multiple times for an object, this is far safer than storing an instance of an object? I am using Linq To Sql, i am not sure if the support for caching is any good.

Comment: would you say the example provided by @mellamokb is good enough? I mean all my calls to an asp.net mvc action method will usually be in one web request (not really set ninject up with this just yet), so I dont feel that the entities will be out of sync, what do you think? To emphasize, I am only ever going to call a service and related code in one web request, in another web request I dont mind calling the database again, (in my head), this means I lost caching ability but it is not too bad for me just yet... thoughts?

Comment: I have done only summary testing, but it seams linq2sql implements identity map at context level so if you query the same context for the same id multiple times, only the first time the query is executed, and for the rest of the query the same Instance of the object is returned - so as long as you perform the queryies on the same instance of the L2S data context you should not worry about keeping state since linq does it for you. As a(nother) rule of thumb don't optimize without hard facts and measured numbers.

Comment: I guess in my scenarios I am not really even trying to optimize just yet, yes I am keeping an eye on it, but I only wanted to ensure the logic for getting some data remains consistent on that entire class, thanks for all this info, really appreciated +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem with being stateful in your services is that the lifespan of the Service class instance needs to be considered.

For example, if your service is exposed via WCF, then the default instancing mode of 'per call' will negate any state between method calls, as each call will mean that a new service instance is created for each call from the client. However, you could use InstanceContextMode.PerSession to 'keep' the connection between client and service up between calls, which would then give you some benefit of the state, although it also has the downside that scalability can be limited as your client ultimately now has control over server resources used in your state.

@mellamokb's point is great, in that one of the common uses of state in SOA is caching.